# Selecting .class elements within parent form

Tags: jquery

I have two FORMs with .ERROR class within both. How can I select .ERROR in THIS form.

Something along the lines of:

```
<script>

$(document).on('click','.SUBMIT',function()
{
    if($(this).closest('form').find('.ERROR').is(':visible'))
    {
        alert('ITS VISIBLE!!!!');
    }
}

</script>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="ERROR" style="display:none;"></div>
    <input type="button" class="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: can you share the relevant html sample.. also what is this refering to

Comment: That looks about right. Why are all of your classes in uppercase?

Comment: I added an example. I have two forms, and I do not want the errors of one to conflict with the other. So when I submit images and get errors, those errors will be ignored (although not accepted), when the user submit the rest of the information in the other half of the form. So I need to separate class .ERROR from each from each.

Comment: if($(this.form).find('.ERROR').is(':visible')) WORKED perfectly. Thanks @Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catching *click* events on form submit buttons is usually not very reliable as there are other events that can submit the form. Instead, catch the *submit* event, eg

```
+function($) {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {

        var form = $(this),
            error = form.find('.ERROR');
        if (error.is(':visible')) {
            alert("IT'S VISIBLE");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: Phil, Your code is amazing. But, how can I do, if error is not visible, invoke default submit? I tried function(e){ return true; } but it screws with all my other code